# How to rapidly expand a data frame based on groups and a new column?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a dataframe of users that are in a panel, and I want to expand it so that this df includes all users and the dates when they appeared in the panel.

Example of the panel data.table:

```r
userid first_date last_date
1: 001 2020-01-01 2023-01-01
2: 002 2020-07-28 2022-12-15
---
1000: 1000 2021-05-14 2022-09-01
```

Hence, I'm doing the following :

```r
panel <- panel %>% 
  group_by(userid) %>%
  reframe(date = seq(from = first_date, to = last_date, by = "1 day"))
```

This operation runs smoothly and in the end I have what I wanted, a panel where each observation is a unique combination of userid and date, but avoiding something like `expand.grid`, since it would have forced me to include also those user-dates for moments when users were not in the panel.

However, after this, I need to include whether a user appears in the panel for a specific product (out of 3) on that date (here I don't care about discriminating, so each row will appear 3 times).

When trying different alternatives, either in `tidyr` or `data.table`, it runs very slow (**Note: The result of the previous code block has 1M rows, which are exactly 1M groups when doing a `group_by`**).

Here is what I've tried:

`tidyr`

```r
panel %>% 
  group_by(userid, date) %>% 
  tidyr::expand(product = c("ProductA", "ProductB", "ProductC"))
```

`data.table`

```r
panel_time_info <- as.data.table(panel_time_info) # This is a very quick operation so it doesn't affect runtime
panel_time_info[, CJ(product = c("ProductA", "ProductB", "ProductC")), keyby = .(userid, date)]
```

But both alternatives are very slow just because of the unnecessary groupings. I feel like there should be a faster way of simply expanding each row by three with those three values, without needing to find all groups as they are already unique from the previous step.

***Note: Given that for this case the number of groups in product is way smaller than the number of groups resulting from several years of daily dates, a very efficient and easy solution is first expanding to products, and then expanding to dates. But if this wasn't the case I feel there should be an easier option.***

Comment: Hi Alberto! I think when data.table is too slow, you know there is something wrong with your approach, not with the code itself (not to say that data.table is blazingly fast all the time, but still)

Comment: from what I understand, for each row r, you are creating d rows, where d is the days between first_date and last_date, and then creating p columns, where p is the number of products. As you can see, this is making the number of rows r*d*p, which in your case (and probably in many others) makes it grow to an unmanageable size, due to exponential growth

Comment: a few different questions: 1. how sparse is the dataset (i.e. for a user whose first date and last date are 2020-07-28 and 2022-12-15 respectively, what is the total for the number of times a typical user tests any product?

Comment: 2. do you think going from users to days to products is the right approach? I would think you would want to start with the product testing events, then assign a TRUE for those users for the particular day, then for all else make it FALSE